# return from incompatible pointer types

Tags: objective-c, pointers

The below code generates the incompatible pointer type error:

```
char *PLURAL(int objects, NSString *singluar, NSString *pluralised) {
return objects ==1 ? singluar:pluralised;}
```

I am new to objective-C and programming in general so can some one help me with this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the return value to NSString* and you should be fine. You are specifying a return value of char* but actually returning NSString*.

Comment: Thanks :) I have marked this as the solution since this was the first answer. 
@ptomato and @Felix King, thanks to you guys too :)

Answer (score 3):

An `NSString *` is not the same as a `char *` (or "C-string" in Objective C terminology). You can't convert a pointer from one to the other implicitly like that. You'll have to use a method like `cStringUsingEncoding`. Also, `NSString` is immutable, so you'll have to return a `const char *`.

Alternatively, you could simply return the `NSString *` instead of `char *`.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
NSString *PLURAL(int objects, NSString *singluar, NSString *pluralised) {
    return objects ==1 ? singluar:pluralised;
}
```

`char *` is not `NSString` !